# How can I integrate OneLogin php toolkit to work with AWS Marketplace?

Tags: onelogin

I am using OneLogin PHP toolkit but it is being spawned by an AWS Marketplace call. OneLogin authenticates fine and then starts up my application. The issue is that AWS Marketplace posts a token to OneLogin php toolkit when it calls.  But this token is needed for my app to handshake with AWS. My problem is communicating that token to my application (so it can do the handshake). It seems that OneLogin is stripping the token off, before starting my app. And I can't seem to find it (in OneLogin php toolkit) and pass it to my app.

Any idea how to get the aws token and pass the aws token to my app after OneLogin has authenticated the user? Is there some type function in OneLogin to pass data through to the target?

I had hoped to get the AWS token from the same session variable where OneLogin stores the authenticated user's email. But the token is not in there.